# Enable PHP extensions Google App Engine (Laravel Web App)

Tags: php, laravel, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I am having trouble when deploying my Laravel 6.2 web application. The problem obviously comes from the phpoffice/phpspreadsheet library.

The problem is I don't know how to modify the php ini file stored on google app engine.

Screenshot from the terminal
[image]

Thanks for your help !

Comment: flex or standard?

Comment: I'm on a flex environment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're on App Engine Flex, you can [enable PHP extensions using composer](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/php/runtime#using_php_extensions).

```
// composer.json
{
  "require": {
    "ext-gd": "*"
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked ! Can't tell you how grateful I am. Thank you !

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do it with the standard environment? They say to use php.ini in documentation. If thats the case, where should we keep ini file?